# Breakpoint inside external library that I made

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have 2 C# projects that I am working on. Project A is a library that Project B uses. I have Project A set to automatically copy the .dll into Project B's directory and then Project B uses that copied file for its reference.

Both projects are set to `DEBUG` and have been cleaned many times. My issue is that if in Project B I go into references -> my external library -> view in assembly explorer and then I try to put a breakpoint somewhere in that code (so I can see exactly when and where a certain part of my external library is being called), the breakpoint always hallows out and says the symbols have not been loaded, even though I can confirm in the Modules window that it says "Symbols Loaded" for the .dll that I am trying to put a breakpoint inside of.

I've set debug info to full inside of Project A and rebuilt it multiple times to try to fix this issue. Is there something I am doing wrong here? All I want to do is put a breakpoint inside of the .dll made in Project A that I can step into during the runtime of Project B (which references that .dll).

Comment: Did you attach the `exe` to the project, in case if you have a executable that consumes your libraries ?

Comment: I thought that if I included the symbol files that I didn't have to attach Project A onto Project B since B already has all the symbols from A?

Comment: What is the output type of Project A ? `exe` or `dll` ?

Comment: Make sure the PDB is in the same or original location where it was built.

Comment: Attach project `A` (.dll) to an executable directly. It should hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to disable the Just My Code option in Visual Studio.

1. Tools > Options > Debugging > General
2. Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: Already did that as well. Another thing is that if I right click on the property I am trying to debug that is from Project A and go to definition, the actual body of the method/property is missing.